# delete request redirects to not found

Tags: laravel, routes

i have an admin page that contains events and i have a delete link which when clicked gives that error.i have include a hidden input in my form

```
<input type="hidden" name="_method" value="delete"/>
```

delete link

```
<a href="{{ route('events.delete', $event->id) }} ">Delete</a>
```

This is the route

```
Route::delete('/', 'EventsController@destroy')->name('events.delete');
```

This is the destroy function in the EventsController controller

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
        $event=Event::find($id);
        $event->delete();
        return redirect('/admin')->with('success','Event deleted successfully');
    }
```

actually theres no error it justt goes to this URl

http://localhost/churchill/public/?8

Comment: a delete anchor tag?

Comment: show your full delete process from the frontend.

Comment: `when clicked gives that error` share that error ? also share your form tag ??

Comment: i've edited the question @NikleshRaut

Comment: Then why you said as `gives that error` ? and please add form tag also ?

Comment: which form tag?

Comment: @mimikiduchu what is a delete anchor tag?

Comment: that is just an anchor tag ... links cause GET requests

Comment: Did you manage to fix the issue?

Answer (score 1):

delete method need event id
like this:

```
Route::delete('/{id}', 'EventsController@destroy')->name('events.delete');
```

Comment: i already tried that i get the error The GET method is not supported for this route. Supported methods: DELETE.

Comment: @mimikiduchu You should remove `?` from the URL, it should be `.../public/8`.

Comment: but am not the one putting it the URL changes

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues in your code the first is that you don't accepting `{id}` in your route

it should be:

```
Route::delete('/{id}', 'EventsController@destroy')->name('events.delete');
```

Also to call `delete` `route` from `view` you have to do something like following:

```
<form action="{{ route('events.delete', ['id' => $event->id  ])}}" method="post">
   @METHOD('DELETE')
   @csrf
   <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

This is called `method spoofing` you can read more about it [here](https://laravel.com/docs/6.x/routing#form-method-spoofing).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

It is because you are using an anchor tag instead of a button or submit input.

An anchor tag always preforms a get request and it doesn't care about the form at all. Since you want a POST request (or delete) you must use an input or button type submit. The only case that you can use an anchor tag to submit a form is when you are using javascript to submit the form.

Here is the code for a submit button:

```
<button type="submit">Delete</button>
```

Example of a delete form:

```
<form method="POST" action="{{ route('events.delete', $event->id) }} }}">
    @method('DELETE')
    @csrf
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```